# How to make Azure Functions to continuously consume/process Azure Service Bus Queue messages in order?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, message-queue, azureservicebus

*(Disclaimer: I'm new to both Message Queues and the Azure Functions)*

I have a Azure Service Bus Queue. And it uses the FIFO technique, which is what I needed. I've also successfully setup a job that keeps pushing the Messages into the Queue. I now have about 100K of Messages in the queue which **have been put in correct order**.

Now, I need to consume/process those Messages **in order**. The processing of each Message takes about 1 second each. But I only know the approach using "Timer Function" in Azure Functions, when it comes to self processing. But again, when I use "Timer Function", I need to run, say, every 5mins and then I need to pull, say, about 300 messages each time. My codes would look like this (I'm using NodeJS):

function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

index.js

```
..
..
let allMessages = [];   
while (allMessages.length < 300) {
    const messages = await sbReceiver.receiveMessages(300, {
        maxWaitTimeInMs: 60 * 1000,
    });
    
    if (!messages.length) {
        break;
    }
    
    allMessages.push(...messages);
    
    for (let message of messages) {
        
        await axios({
            /**
             * PROCESS SINGLE MESSAGE HERE
             * TAKES ABOUT 1 SEC EACH
             */
        })
        .then(async function (response) {
            await sbReceiver.completeMessage(message);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            break;
        });
        
    }
}
..
..
```

This approach does the work done just fine. But I'm just not satisfied with the idea that I have to do the processings through the a scheduled job (Timer Function).

### Question

Other than using "Timer Functions", is there a way (or) how to make the Azure Function (NodeJS) to **always keep consuming/processing** the Queued Messages on it's own while making sure the Messages are processed in ordered manner?

The key points here are to:

1. To keep consuming/processing the Messages, preferably without using Timers
2. To consume/process the Messages in order

Edit:
I am aware of the "**Azure Service Bus Queue Triggers**", but I do not think those Triggers wait for the previous job to "finish processing". Because my processing involves API call to another side, which needs to be done only one after another in ordered manner. I think Queue Triggers just anyhow got fired as soon as the new Message is arrived, which would then mess up with the ordering at the other end. Please correct me if I was mistaken on that concept.

Thanks in advance for your kind advices.

Comment: Why don't you use Azure Service bus queue trigger directly? This will trigger and process the queues in your service bus?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai will the "queue trigger" make sure if the previous trigger has not done with the processing yet? (There is API call involved) So that the "ordering" at the other end, is not messed up.

Comment: Yes, Along with Service bus queue trigger in your nodejs code, You can make use of deferral method, deferMessage() for more reference read this - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/message-deferral.md > Defer message will keep aside the message in queue or subscription until it can be processed. IF you want I can provide you with the code?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai to my limited knowledge, those Queue Triggers just got fired as soon as the new Message is arrived, not until the previous Message has been cleared out. Now you're saying that the `deferMessage` waits for the previous Message to be cleared out? (By the way, the 'Javascript' link on your article is dead.)

Comment: Yes, The queue trigger will trigger once the new message arrives but you can add the defer queue process block in the same index.js code to process the code, Apologies for the dead link, Looks like the documentation is not updated. Please go to this link https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/v7/javascript/advanced/deferral.js

Comment: Refer this link, Its a complete link to defer js sample -https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/v7/javascript/advanced/deferral.js

Comment: @SiddheshDesai so, it would still be the "Azure Service Bus Queue Trigger" upon the Azure Functions creation, and then the concept of `deferMessage` would be in the codes that I need to write?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai ok I think I got the concept now. It'd be great if you can put that as an answer, so that I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Have a look at this article to see if it helps. I know it talks about storage queue but only the input trigger is different. There are other config which require changes. https://laurakokkarinen.com/forcing-an-azure-function-to-process-queue-storage-messages-one-at-a-time/

Answer (score 2):

***Posting my comments as an answer for the community.***

You directly make use of Azure Service Bus queue trigger to process and defer the message as soon as the queue arrives in the service bus. You can utilise the deferral method, deferMessage(), together with the Service Bus Queue Trigger in your Node.js code. As soon as the new message arrives in the queue. The Azure Service bus queue trigger will trigger the function and then you can add the deferral message code block to defer the message and process it.

You can refer the defer.js code sample code from this [Github repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/v7/javascript/advanced/deferral.js)

Sample service bus js function:-

**index.js:-**

```js
module.exports = async function(context, mySbMsg) {
    context.log('JavaScript ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message', mySbMsg);
};

const { ServiceBusClient, delay } = require("@azure/service-bus");

// Load the .env file if it exists
require("dotenv").config();

// Define connection string and related Service Bus entity names here
const connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://siliconservicebus76.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xcMOcbMJAPnPM+LTl+zRq4Ix2EjHQFkrs+ASbBXJ2v4=";
const queueName = "test";

async function main() {
  await sendMessages();
  await receiveMessage();
}

// Shuffle and send messages
async function sendMessages() {
  const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
  // createSender() can also be used to create a sender for a topic.
  const sender = sbClient.createSender(queueName);

  const data = [
    { step: 1, title: "Shop" },
    { step: 2, title: "Unpack" },
    { step: 3, title: "Prepare" },
    { step: 4, title: "Cook" },
    { step: 5, title: "Eat" },
  ];
  const promises = new Array();
  for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    const message = {
      body: data[index],
      subject: "RecipeStep",
      contentType: "application/json",
    };
    // the way we shuffle the message order is to introduce a tiny random delay before each of the messages is sent
    promises.push(
      delay(Math.random() * 30).then(async () => {
        try {
          await sender.sendMessages(message);
          console.log("Sent message step:", data[index].step);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("Error while sending message", err);
        }
      })
    );
  }
  // wait until all the send tasks are complete
  await Promise.all(promises);
  await sender.close();
  await sbClient.close();
}

async function receiveMessage() {
  const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);

  // If receiving from a subscription, you can use the createReceiver(topicName, subscriptionName) overload
  let receiver = sbClient.createReceiver(queueName);

  const deferredSteps = new Map();
  let lastProcessedRecipeStep = 0;
  try {
    const processMessage = async (brokeredMessage) => {
      if (
        brokeredMessage.subject === "RecipeStep" &&
        brokeredMessage.contentType === "application/json"
      ) {
        const message = brokeredMessage.body;
        // now let's check whether the step we received is the step we expect at this stage of the workflow
        if (message.step === lastProcessedRecipeStep + 1) {
          console.log("Process received message:", message);
          lastProcessedRecipeStep++;
          await receiver.completeMessage(brokeredMessage);
        } else {
          // if this is not the step we expected, we defer the message, meaning that we leave it in the queue but take it out of
          // the delivery order. We put it aside. To retrieve it later, we remeber its sequence number
          const sequenceNumber = brokeredMessage.sequenceNumber;
          deferredSteps.set(message.step, sequenceNumber);
          console.log("Defer received message:", message);
          await receiver.deferMessage(brokeredMessage);
        }
      } else {
        // we dead-letter the message if we don't know what to do with it.
        console.log(
          "Unknown message received, moving it to dead-letter queue ",
          brokeredMessage.body
        );
        await receiver.deadLetterMessage(brokeredMessage);
      }
    };
    const processError = async (args) => {
      console.log(`>>>>> Error from error source ${args.errorSource} occurred: `, args.error);
    };

    receiver.subscribe(
      { processMessage, processError },
      {
        autoCompleteMessages: false,
      }
    ); // Disabling autoCompleteMessages so we can control when message can be completed, deferred or deadlettered
    await delay(10000);
    await receiver.close();
    console.log("Total number of deferred messages:", deferredSteps.size);

    receiver = sbClient.createReceiver(queueName);
    // Now we process the deferred messages
    while (deferredSteps.size > 0) {
      const step = lastProcessedRecipeStep + 1;
      const sequenceNumber = deferredSteps.get(step);
      const [message] = await receiver.receiveDeferredMessages(sequenceNumber);
      if (message) {
        console.log("Process deferred message:", message.body);
        await receiver.completeMessage(message);
      } else {
        console.log("No message found for step number ", step);
      }
      deferredSteps.delete(step);
      lastProcessedRecipeStep++;
    }
    await receiver.close();
  } finally {
    await sbClient.close();
  }
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log("Deferral Sample - Error occurred: ", err);
  process.exit(1);
});

module.exports = { main };
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Hi @SiddheshDesai thanks again for sharing this. Could you also share your "function.json" file contents please? Because when I tried to add the new function as "Azure Service Bus Queue Trigger", the VSCode then gave me 4 prompts, and I was not sure of what to put in last two 3/4 and 4/4 prompts. Thanks.

Comment: This is my function.json select your service bus and type your queue name instead of myinputqueue while creating the function - {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mySbMsg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "test",
      "connection": "siliconservicebus76_SERVICEBUS"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Hi @SiddheshDesai so in the "function.json", you did not need to key in the full "connection string" of your Service Bus (that you can retrieve from the sb dashboard) into the "connection" attribute of this json file? I tried by entering just the name of the sb (as you did), e.g, "myServiceBus", and it didn't work. Then I tried with full connection string, also didn't work.

Comment: I selected my service bus account while creating the function itself from vs code, As I have logged into my Azure account. Can you try using Azure extension in Vs code and create function from there?

Comment: Hi @SiddheshDesai actually that was what I meant. I was trying to create the new Function through the VSCode with Azure Extension enabled. In fact, that's the only way we've been creating/developing/uploading the Azure Functions. But then, we ran into the issue that I mentioned in my previous comments. Therefore, I wonder what would you have entered (in the prompt 3/4 and 4/4) if you had to create new Function through VSCode for this.

Comment: In short: the Function is not getting triggered when the new Messages are added into the Queue.